# How to pass string with trailing whitespace to python's subprocess

Tags: python

I would like to batch rename files that have trailing spaces to the same name without the spaces. In python 3.6.5, the following works fine:

```
subprocess.call("mv '%s' '%s'"%(name,name.strip()),shell=True)
```

However, in python 2.7, I get errors such as "file not found". Is there a way to accomplish what I want in python 2.7?

Update: here is the code

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
   for name in fnmatch.filter(filenames, "randconf*"):     
          if " " in name: 
             subprocess.call('mv "%s" "%s"'%name,name.strip()),shell=True)
```

If I replace the subprocess line with "print name", I get, for example:

```
randconf_1                                                      
randconf_10                                                     
randconf_11                                                     
randconf_12                                                     
randconf_13                                                     
randconf_14                                                     
randconf_15
```

Comment: `shutil.mv(name, name.strip())`

Comment: Thanks, but same story: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'randconf_1   '

Comment: Please could you show more of the script, including the loop that finds all these filenames?

Comment: Linux wtpp024 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.73-2+deb7u3 x86_64 GNU/Linux and Python 2.7.3. Not sure how to pipe the output.

Comment: Your code needs to use the directory paths.

Comment: Bingo! Using "name = os.path.join(dirpath, name)" together with "os.rename(name, name.strip())" works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, as pointed out by @jordanm,  your problem is that you're calling `mv` on the *name* of the files for each of the directory traversed by `os.walk`, but `os.walk` doesn't change the current working directory.

So for those files that are found in subdirectories, that won't work.

You'd need to pass the full path of the file to `mv`, so something like `os.path.join(dirpath, name)`.

Ideally, you'd want the *walking* to change directories as it proceeds like `perl` `File::Find`'s `finddepth()` or BSD/GNU `find -execdir` do, which would make it safer and avoid problems with too deep directory trees, but I don't think you can do that easily with `python`'s `os.walk()`.

Now, there are a few other problems with your code:

### Command injection vulnerability

Now, trailing spaces are the least of your worries in that:

```
subprocess.call("mv '%s' '%s'"%(name,name.strip()),shell=True)
```

That's basically a command injection vulnerability (think for instance of a file called `'$(reboot)'` (with the quotes)).

As a rule, don't embed arbitrary text in strings interpreted as shell code (or code in any language that can do any harm).

With your code (the variant using the `'mv "%s" "%s"'` form), you could have the same error with files called `randconf $x` or `randconf $(test)` for instance.

Here, use:

```
subprocess.call(("mv", "--", name, name.strip()),shell=False)
```

If you do have to use a shell, a better way to pass data to that shell is to use environment variables:

```
os.putenv("OLD", name)
os.putenv("NEW", name.strip())
subprocess.call('mv -- "$OLD" "$NEW"',shell=True)
```

Running a shell is also expensive. Especially on systems where `sh` is actually a large full-featured shell like `bash`, `ksh93` or `zsh` that generally take a significant time to load and initialize.

While you're at calling the shell, you might as well do the whole finding and renaming in the shell code.

### Ambiguity of `mv`

`mv` is not a command with the best interface (`cp` and `ln` have the same issues). The problem is that `mv` does many different things, but not based on what/how you ask it, but on context.

```
mv A B
```

Either

- renames A to B/A if B existed and was of type *directory* or *symlink to directory* on the same file system
- does the same but with a copy (preserving as many attributes as possible) followed by delete if the rename would cross a filesystem boundary
- does a rename otherwise (deleting the target if it existed beforehand)

Here, you just want a basic `rename()` system call, or maybe better a `rename()` that doesn't clobber an already existing file (like Linux' `renameat2(... RENAME_NOREPLACE)`), which would also alleviate issues  like both `"randconf_1 "` and `"randconf_1  "` being renamed to `randonf_1`.

With GNU `mv`, you can do that with:

```
mv -nT -- "$old" "$new"
```

but that's not portable. (Also note that GNU `mv` doesn't use `renameat2()` on Linux, so does have a (minor here) race condition)

In any case, in `python`, you don't have to call a separate program just to rename a file.

```
os.rename(name, name.strip());
```

(I don't thing `python` has a binding to Linux' `renameat2()`)

### space vs whitespace

`python`'s `strip()` strips leading and trailing *whitespace* characters. Here all strings start with `randconf`, so it's the same as `rstrip()`. *whitespace* includes the ASCII space character, but all sorts of other vertical and horizontal spacing characters (only ASCII ones it would seem though), like TAB, LF, CR...

As your looking for files that *contain* space characters anywhere in the line, you could end up not renaming some file names that end with whitespace (like  `"randconf_\t"` that doesn't contain any space), or call `mv` for file names that don't end in whitespace (like `"randconf_x y"`).

You could use `fnmatch.filter(filenames, "randconf* ")` and `rstrip(" ")` if you only care about trailing space characters

### POSIX shell equivalent:

Do do that with POSIX shell and utility syntax:

```
find . -depth -name 'randconf*[[:space:]]' ! -type d -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    newfile=${file%"${file##*[![:space:]]}"}
    [ -e "$newfile" ] || [ -L "$newfile" ] || mv -- "$file" "$newfile"
  done' sh {} +
```

Or slighly more reliable with GNU utilities

```
find . -depth -name 'randconf*[[:space:]]' ! -type d -execdir bash -O extglob -c '
  for file do
    newfile=${file%*([[:space:]])}
    mv -nT -- "$file" "$newfile"
  done' sh {} +
```

(note that it strips all the characters considered as whitespace in the current locale, not just the ASCII ones like in python; change the locale to `C` to only match ASCII whitespace).

Comment: Thanks, you are very right about this. (I do test for specific filenames though, hence I got lucky and did not encounter anything that could be system command).